# 200V AC to 5V DC converter

Tags: conversion

I have to convert the output of my sensor 200 VAC to 5VDC.The following figure represents how i have proceed [image: transformer-rectification-smoothing-regulation]

This technic is bulky  and I'm looking for an other solution to assure the conversion. I'm asking about the possibility to replace the regulator and the transformater by zener diode ?
sensor :  http://www.schmersal.net/datenblatt?lang=fr&produkt=jen734750428mktzdbx27351nndisv
the conversion is needed to assure the connection with the STM32F04 with an input of 5VDC

Comment: Does your sensor produce a constant amplitude 200VAC? Does its frequency change much?

Comment: How much current do you need from the 5V.  You can get away with just a zener and resistor if its just to detect its there but we need to be more clever if you want to get useful power out of it?

Comment: Provide a link to the sensor datasheet or at least specify what kind of sensor it is and the expected output specs.

Comment: What kind of sensor you have is very important to getting a proper answer to the question.  You said 200VAC, but at what frequency? Does the voltage or frequency vary? does it encode data on the line? This will be important to know, and maybe your solution (despite its wrong caps) will not work anyways because it might cause you to actually lose the information you are trying to extract.

Answer (score 5):

This question is so badly researched and phrased so let's uncover what the OP is talking about. The sensor in question is a reed type proximity sensor and this is a picture of the English language version of it with a couple of salient points: -

[image]

What the OP needs is a better understanding of this sensor. He almost certainly doesn't want to convert an AC voltage of 200V to 5V (he thinks he does but the confusion arises because of the graph in the picture above).

It is highly likely that all the OP needs to do is use the reed contact output from the sensor and a pull-up resistor to 5V. Feed that to the STM32F04 and all should be well.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic appears to be a power supply rather than a sensor connection, with some errors (polarity of both capacitors and regulator part number).

This kind of linear power supply is indeed bulky and wasteful of power, but a zener would not be any better.

In general to replace a transformer with non-isolated circuitry leads to a serious decrease in safety due to loss of galvanic isolation. If you need to ask about this, I would suggest that you not attempt to use a non-isolated power supply.

Usually small, light isolated supplies are made with switching power supplies which incorporate smaller lighter transformers. An easy route to such a supply is to use a switching wall-plug adapter (such as this one from A.C. Ryan).

[image]

On the other hand, if you are simply trying to detect the presence of the 200VAC line voltage, a viable (and potentially safe) transformerless approach is to use an AC-input optoisolator. For example, the [MID400](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MI/MID400.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Maybe OP wants to sense line voltage :)

Comment: @BrianOnn .. and it's not enough challenge to directly measure it, hence the regulator to make it more difficult.

Comment: LOL.. and as I also said in a comment, the sensor might use some modulation scheme to encode the data, all of which will be lost in a voltage regulator conversion to 5V.. hence we need to know what being used as the sensor here.

Comment: It could be a simple on/off sensor (limit switch, for example), in which case an AC-input optoisolator might do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Something is wrong with the capacitors on this picture )))
May be you should try to use another transformer? Not 1:1 but 1:100?
Then you may use common diode to rectify the voltage, and an op amp as a buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBuugz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but it does (with the recently added schematic) attempt to answer the question. Should not be deleted.